# SQL Server join query not retrieving proper result

Tags: sql-server

1. Select the list of all dealers whose vehicles are never assigned to any customer i.e that vehicle is not present in `PS3_VehicleBooking`, and committed date is greater than today's date.

3 tables to be used are-

```
CREATE TABLE PS3_Dealer(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary KEY,
    DealerID varchar(255) NULL,
    DealerName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ContactNo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    NoOfVehicles bigint NOT NULL,
    CommittedDate date NOT NULL
);

create table PS3_Vehicle 
  (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    DealerID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    VehicleID varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    VehicleName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Capacity BIGINT NOT NULL

  );

  create table PS3_VehicleBooking
  (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
  BookingID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  VehicleID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  StartDate date NOT NULL,
  EndDate date NOT NULL
  );
```

PS3_Dealer values-

```
DealerID DealerName ContactNo NoOfVehicles CommittedDate
1        ng         9         5             2013-12-12
2        nikki      5         7             2013-12-25
3        nik        4         6             2013-10-11
4        hj         2         2             2014-11-10
5        pk         67        8             2013-10-10
```

PS3_Vehicle

```
DealerID VehicleID VehicleName Capacity
1        V1        ind         4
2        V2        innova      5
3        V3        innova      6
1        V4        ula         8
4        V5        hkk         2
5        V6        ghi         9
2        V7        bjhgi       4
```

PS3_VehicleBooking-

```
BookingID VehicleID StartDate     EndDate
  1         V1      2013-12-13     2013-12-17 
  2         V2      2013-10-11     2013-10-13
  3         V3      2014-12-10     2014-12-13
  4         V4      2012-10-10     2012-10-13
  5         V2      2013-12-14     2013-12-18
```

expected outcome-

```
DealerID  DealerName ContactNo NoOfVehicles CommittedDate

4          hj        2          2           2014-11-10
```

but i am getting-

```
DealerID  DealerName ContactNo NoOfVehicles CommittedDate

4          hj        2          2           2014-11-10
2          Nikki     5          7           2013-12-25
```

i dont want dealer id 2 in result because V2 provided by dealer id 2 is present in PS3_Booking.

My query is-

```
SELECT h.DealerID,
       h.DealerName,
       h.ContactNo,
       h.NoOfVehicles,
       h.CommittedDate
FROM   PS3_Dealer h
       INNER JOIN(SELECT DealerID,
                         PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID
                  FROM   PS3_Vehicle
                         LEFT JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking
                           ON PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID = PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID) w
         ON h.DealerID = w.DealerID
WHERE  w.VehicleID IS NULL
       AND h.CommittedDate > GETDATE()
```

please correct where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to actually answer the question**

You were getting Nikki because there does exist a car for her (V7) that is not in the booking table.
This should exclude Nikki.

```
SELECT h.DealerID,
   h.DealerName,
   h.ContactNo,
   h.NoOfVehicles,
   h.CommittedDate
FROM PS3_Dealer d
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT *
  FROM PS3_VehicleBookingb
  JOIN PS3_Vehiclev ON b.vehicleID = v.VehicleID
  JOIN PS3_Dealerd2 ON d2.dealerID = v.dealerID
  WHERE d2.dealerID = d.dealerID)
AND CommittedDate > Current_date()
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb365/19

Comment: this query is also giving dealer id 2 in result,i dont want that row because dealer id as 2 has one vehicle present in PS3_vehicleBOOKing

Comment: this is not giving a any result

Comment: sorry. I fixed it to check for the ID in Booking instead of vehicle.
I realized this is still returning two results becuase there does exist a car (V7) that doesn't have a booking for Nikki. I'm not certain if that should be intended or not.

Comment: fixed the query and included the sqlfiddle that I used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DealerID 2 has 2 Vehicles.  One that has booking, and the other does not.  When you run

```
SELECT DealerID,
        PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID
FROM   PS3_Vehicle
        LEFT JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking
        ON PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID = PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID
```

You will get one record that has DealerID 2 with NULL VehicleID and the other none NULL Vehicle ID.

You can try to the run the statement below to get the desired results (may not be the most optimal, but it is a fix to your statement):

```
SELECT h.DealerID,
       h.DealerName,
       h.ContactNo,
       h.NoOfVehicles,
       h.CommittedDate
FROM   PS3_Dealer h
       INNER JOIN(SELECT DealerID,
                         MAX(PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID) as VehicleID
                  FROM   PS3_Vehicle
                         LEFT JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking
                           ON PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID = PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID
                    GROUP BY DealerID
                    ) w
         ON h.DealerID = w.DealerID
WHERE  w.VehicleID IS NULL
       AND h.CommittedDate > GETDATE()
```

Comment: this is working fine but it is giving two more columns dealer id and vehicle id which i dont want in result and here dealerid column is coming two times

Comment: Thanks,it is working now as expected,can you please expalain what is w.*?

Comment: just for testing, I was returning the the columns returned by the subquery.

Comment: @user3054094 It stands for "wet." It allows SQL Server to perform faster.